# How to replace clip preserving trimming in Final Cut Pro X?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

How can I replace an already trimmed clip with a new one so that the trim start and end positions are preserved?

Answer (score 0):

- Open the existing clip.
- Replace the inner clip (the start of it will be in a gray area which represents the trimming).

Warning: Audio properties such as Pan are lost during the process.

Answer (score 0):

In the Browser select the clip you want to use. Then go to the position this new clip you want to start. Then hit “I” on the keyboard to mark the in point, don’t mind the end point, the remaining clip must be long enough though. Then get your mouse into the yellow highlighted area. Drag it over the clip you want replace in your timeline and hover for a moment, until your mouse show the plus symbol. Now let go, a menu will show up. Choose “Replace from Start”. The new clip will replace the old in the timeline but the cut points from the timeline won’t change.